# Bond energies database

Tags: computational-chemistry

I’m looking for a public database of bond energies of biochemical compounds. Does one exist?

Otherwise, which is the standard computational methodology to calculate them? Any references would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Chemistry StackExchange! What are you looking for specifically? An table of covalent bond energies? These exist (and are widely available in textbooks and on the net) but are not specific to biomolecules. Or are you talking about binding energies of pairs of molecules?

Comment: thanks, precisely covalent bond energies is what I'm looking for. Despite I'm interested in biochemical compounds, please let me know the net resources that you comment.

Comment: Have you searched [NIST](http://webbook.nist.gov)?

Answer (score 4):

The Comprehensive Handbook of Chemical Bond Energies might be able to help.  It walks through bonds in different functional groups.  It can be found at http://www.ebah.com.br/content/ABAAABH2cAD/comprehensive-handbook-of-chemical-bond-energies-0849373662